# Mass update taking to long

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

After searching through many posts I have come up with the code below to handle updating 200,000 to 2 million records daily. The problem is its still takes hours to complete, I have tried to narrow down the records that are updated to only those I need. I'm really new to this but it seems like updating 200,000 records should go pretty fast. Please review the code below and see if I am doing something wrong? Thanks in Advance

P.S. Why is my code not going in a code box?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#MinDate') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MinDate 
GO

SELECT * INTO #MinDate 
FROM 
    (  
    SELECT  n1.TR_SerNum, Min(n1.TR_Scan_Date) As MinDate
    FROM IMB_TBO_Data.dbo.TBO_Trace_Data as t1  
        INNER JOIN Trace_Return_Updates as n1 
        ON t1.TR_SerNum = n1.TR_SerNum
    WHERE (n1.TR_Scan_Date < t1.First_Scan_Date)
        OR (IsDate(n1.TR_Scan_Date) = 1) AND (t1.First_Scan_Date Is Null)
    GROUP BY n1.TR_SerNum
    ) as n 
GO


CREATE INDEX IDX_SerNum ON #MinDate(TR_SerNum)
GO

DECLARE  @UPDATES TABLE (PK_ID int NOT NULL Primary KEY)

DECLARE @x INT

SET @x = 0

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TOP (10000) IMB_TBO_Data.dbo.TBO_Trace_Data 
            SET First_Scan_Date = n.MinDate
        OUTPUT inserted.TR_SerNum INTO @Updates
        FROM IMB_TBO_Data.dbo.TBO_Trace_Data t
            INNER JOIN #MinDate n
            ON t.TR_SerNum = n.TR_SerNum
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT * FROM @UPDATES AS Updates
            WHERE UPDates.PK_ID = t.TR_SerNum)
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'
    END
SET ROWCOUNT  0
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#MinDate') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MinDate;
GO

PRINT N'Update First Scan Date'"
```

Comment: Please update 'sql' to show the type of SQL server you are using.  Is it Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Did you check for blocking? Did you check for log growth events?

Comment: Why is `@x` declared?